# Why does this print the width all the time for the circle?

Tags: c++, methods, enums, console, structure

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

const double PI = 3.141592653589793238463;

enum Figur {DREIECK, RECHTECK, KREIS};

struct Geo {
    mutable Figur figur;
    mutable double a, b, c;
};

Geo createGeo(Figur f, double a, double b, double c)
{
    Geo d;
    d.figur = f;
    d.a = a;
    d.b = b;
    d.c = c;
    return d;
}

Geo getGeo() {
    double a=0.0, b=0.0, c=0.0;
n:
    cout << "Please insert which geometrical object you want to create:" << endl;
    cout << "0 for triangle" << endl << "1 for rectangle" << endl << "2 for circle" << endl;
    Figur f;
    int p = 3;
    cin >> p;
    if (p == 0)
    {
        f = DREIECK;

        cout << "Please insert the length: ";
        cin >> a;

        cout << endl << "Please insert the width: ";
        cin >> b;

        {   m:
                cout << endl << "Please set the angle >0 and <180°: ";
                cin >> c;
                if (c <= 0 || c >= 180)
                {
                    cout << endl << "Invalid value! Please try again" << endl;
                    goto m;
                }
        }
        cout << endl << "Your figure is now going to be created" << endl;
        Geo geo = createGeo(f, a, b, c);
        return geo;
    }
    else if (p == 1)
    {
        f = RECHTECK;
        cout << "Please insert the length: ";
        cin >> a;
        cout << endl << "Please insert the width: ";
        cin >> b;
        cout << endl << "Your figure is now going to be created" << endl;
        Geo geo = createGeo(f, a, b ,0);
        return geo;
    }
    else if (p == 2)
    {
        f = KREIS;
        cout << "Please insert the radius: ";
        cin >> a;
        cout << endl << "Your figure is now going to be created" << endl;
        Geo geo = createGeo(f, a,0,0);
        return geo;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid value. Please try again." << endl;
        goto n;
    }


}


double flaeche(Geo const &g)
{
    double flaeche;
    if(g.figur = DREIECK) 
    {
        flaeche = 0.5 * g.a*g.b;
    }
    else if (g.figur = RECHTECK)
    {
        flaeche = g.a*g.b;
    }

    else if(g.figur = KREIS)
    {
        flaeche = PI * pow(g.a, 2);
    }

    return flaeche;
}

void putGeo(double a, Geo &g)
{
    string typ;
    if (g.figur == DREIECK) typ = "triangle";
    else if (g.figur == RECHTECK) typ = "rectangle";
    else typ = "circle";
    cout << "Type of figure: " << typ << endl;
    if (g.figur == DREIECK) {
        cout << "Length: " << g.a << endl;
        cout << "Height: " << g.b << endl;
        cout << "Angle: " << g.a << endl;
        cout << "Area: " << a << endl;
    }
    else if (g.figur == RECHTECK) {
        cout << "Length: " << g.a << endl;
        cout << "Width: " << g.b << endl;
        cout << "Area: " << a << endl;
    }
    else if(g.figur == KREIS){
        cout << "Radius: " << g.a << endl;
        cout << "Area: " << a << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Geo g1 = getGeo();

    double a = flaeche(g1);

    putGeo(a, g1);

    return 0;
}
```

Hello,

I hope this code sample is easy for you to understand.
I wanted to create a program in which the user must create an geometrical object through the console.

Rectangle and triangle are working quite well for now, but with the circle there is a little problem.

Everytime I when I create a circle and call the putGeo() method, the width is going to be printed aswell and the area is calculated with zero.

Has somebody maybe an idea why this is so?

It's an exercise from my course and right now I have really no more idea.

The program was in German completely but I translated the output. For the enum DREIECK is triangle, RECHTECK is rectangle and KREIS is circle.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT PROBLEM WITH OUTPUT**

If I create the circle with a radius of 5

I want to get printed though putGeo()

Radius: 5
Area: 78.5398163397

But I actually get

Radius: 5
Width: 0
Area: 0

Comment: What's the exact output that you're getting, and what are you expecting to to get?

Comment: For example if I input a radius of 5 for the circle, I want to get 5^2*PI for the are. so area should be 78.5398163397. With the putGeo() I just want to get the type, the radius and the area printed so:

Type: circle
radius: 5
Area: 78.5398163397

Comment: And what's the problem? Again, show the output you're getting vs what you expect to get, and post it in the question itself.

Comment: ok changed - hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:

```
if(g.figur = DREIECK)
```

You intended a *test,* but this is an *assignment.* This sets the value of `g.figur` to `DREIECK`. After this, the area will be calculated incorrectly.

A good compiler will warn you when you use an assignment in this way. (If you suppress or ignore compiler warnings, you create trouble for yourself.)

The correct form is

```
if(g.figur == DREIECK)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I oversaw that all the time.

Problem solved